# Crash involving gcroot<> and garbage collection while native threads are running

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, c++-cli

I have native C++ object `Object1` holding a reference to a managed one:

```
   class Object1 
   {
      Object2* parent_;
      gcroot<Observer^> obs_;

      // ctor
      Object1(Object2* parent, Observer^ obs) : parent_(parent), obs_(obs) {} 

      void Execute(void)
      {
         parent_->Execute2(obs_);
      }
   };
```

Function `Execute2()` is a member of another native object and executes code like:

```
void Object2::Execute2(Observer^ obs)
{
... allocate some managed object data = gcnew(...

   obs->OnNext(data);
```

The use case is that `Object1` gets created and put on the queue. Then a separate native thread pops the queue,
calls Execute -> Execute2 -> OnNext() and then deletes unmanaged `Object1`.

Managed object happens to derive from, and implement Reactive Extensions `IObserver` interface, so that's why I call `OnNext()` on it.
Apparently under the heavy loads (implying GC gets called) program crashes due to InvalidOperationException ("Handle is not initialized.")
with the following crash dump stack (cleaned up to make it more readable):

```
[Managed to Native Transition]  
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.FromIntPtr(System.IntPtr value)
<Module>.gcroot<Observer^>.->()
<Module>.Object2.Execute2(Observer obs)
<Module>.Object1.Execute() 
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

However, value passed to `FromIntPtr` is not null, which would be one way to cause the exception. Also, I am fairly confident
that, when contructing `Object1`, null handle could not be passed as obs parameter (but see point 3 below).

Thus, the only three possible causes of the crash that come to my mind are:

1. managed object held in gcroot was disposed
2. GC moved the reference to managed object, then unmanaged thread tries to get GCHandle from a wrong pointer. That is, GC hasn't fixed it yet to refer to managed object's new location.
3. managed object was collected before it was stored in `Object1`. This code path goes like:

   C# code:

   ```
        Observer obs = new Observer;
        SomeManagedObject.StoreObserver(obs);
   ```

   C++/CLI code:

   ```
        StoreObserver(Observer^ obs)
        {
          Object1 obj1 = new Object1(ptrObject2, obs);
   ```

I am leaning to exclude 1 as the cause, because gcroot destructor gets called only when `Object1` is deleted. That doesn't happen until the
call to Execute has returned. Thus GC should not collect managed object held by `gcroot`.

2 seems possible since GC doesn't know about unmanaged threads and these can be executing 'in the middle' of GC process.
Often you will find the statement that **managed object stored in gcroot doesn't need to be pinned.** This appears to be
that case when it should.

I have a hard time imagining how 3 can happen.

Can anybody shed some light on this and either support or show my reasoning wrong?
The crash is intermittent and I would like some feedback before I attempt to experiment with pinned pointers.

Comment: 4. A standard heap corruption bug overwrote the gcroot.

Comment: Ok, so I may put some sentinel bytes around gcroot in native object to try confirm that. Does 1 or 3 strike you as unlikely, though?

Comment: 5. While the GC was updating the location in the gcroot, another thread used it and saw a partially updated value (I do not know if the underlying type is atomic).  This shouldn't be an issue since only managed code can read from a gcroot and it should be paused during gc... But more likely than the first options.

Comment: @BenVoigt **only managed code can read from a gcroot and it should be paused during gc**  - but in the case of mixed-mode, native code with transitions to managed code and back, this code seems to be executing on native thread only?! Or does transition automatically imply thread switch?

Comment: No thread switch. But the garbage collector should become aware of all running managed code even if the thread was created by native code.

Comment: @Tony So you used pin_ptr ?